# Navigating records from a SharePoint table using a listbox

Tags: vba, ms-access, sharepoint

So, I have moved my table to Sharepoint and linked my frontend
but my listbox has stopped working. The recordsource on the form is a query.

On the `AfterUpdate` Event of the list box, I have:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

If IsNull(sNo) Or IsNull(sName) Or IsNull(sClass) Then
Exit Sub
End If

If Not IsNull(sNo) And Not IsNull(sName) And Not IsNull(sClass) Then
    Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
    rs.FindFirst ("[sNo] = '" & Me![listBox] & "'")
    If Not rs.NoMatch Then
        Me.Dirty = False
        Me.Bookmark = rs.Bookmark
        Else
        Exit Sub
    End If
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
End If
```

This worked before with a local table but now it doesn't as the table has been moved to Sharepoint.
I assume it is something to do with the recordset but I don't know. How do I get along with this?
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with "doesn't work"? Errors, just doesn't navigate, something else?

Comment: @ErikA There is no error at all. The code does not do anything

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't do anything? Have you set breakpoint and step debugged? Does event run?

Comment: Move `Me.Dirty = False` to the top of your code.

Comment: @Gustav Moving `Me.Dirty = Fales` to the top of the code did not work either. On using `Debug.print sNo` the code always points to the first record no matter which record you chose from the list box.  Its as though the focus is stack onto that one record.

Comment: Then it probably is a Sharepoint feature.

Comment: @June7 Yes I did, and the row source of the list box is `SELECT * FROM qryStudents;`

Comment: @Gustav on changing the bound columns from 2 to 1 on the property of the list box it seems to be working again.